# How to increase description word wrap limit in laravel backpack column?

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

[image]I am using laravel backpack for my one project. I am stuck in one place where in the list of data the description column showing limited words in the column. I want to show full description in list column itself.

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
   'label' => "Message",
   'type' => 'text',
   'name' => 'message'
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do that using `'limit' => 20000`. Here's this field's definition [from the docs](https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-columns-types#section-text):

```
[
   'name' => 'name', // The db column name
   'label' => "Tag Name", // Table column heading
   // 'prefix' => "Name: ",
   // 'suffix' => "(user)",
   // 'limit' => 120, // character limit; default is 80;
],
```

Hope it helps. Cheers!

Comment: You also have to set the rows to no-wrap :/

Comment: Is there any way I can wrap long text( multiple line)?